# Trying to utilize cards.dll on 64-bit Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am trying to utilize the "cards.dll" module to create a visual card game, and I can't seem to figure it out despite all of the Googling I can think to do. I have the DLL file (203,024 bytes) but I'm confused about the "registration" as a .NET or a COM assembly. I have tried:

- adding it as a reference (from within Visual Studio 2015)
  [image: reference could not be added]
- Explicitly loading it

  Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(@"/cards.dll");

with the result:
**The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)**

- I have tried `regsvr32.exe cards.dll`, (with and without `/u` and `/i`) but I get the message:
  [image]

I have copied the DLL into the C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folders as well, but to no avail.

I'm running this (or at least trying to) on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine, with an i5 core.

Here's the dumpbin output on it.
[image: dumpbin output]

Comment: There are lots of DLLs around that are not a COM server so don't contain a type library and are not a .NET assembly so don't contain metadata.  Use Dumpbin.exe /exports to see if it contains any exported functions that you can pinvoke.  And in VS use File > Open > File and select the DLL to see if it contains any unmanaged resources.  Bitmaps would be likely.  Somebody owns the copyright on this, give them a call.

Comment: dumpbin shows no exported items. Here's what Visual Studio shows: http://prntscr.com/d36tvb I didn't think this would be a mysterious file - it is advertised as THE dll file that standard games like Solitaire use.

Comment: Cards.dll is most likely not a COM library. It's most likely a standard DLL that does not require registration. Unless, of course, it was rewritten for absolutely no reason recently, because it's been around since long before .NET even existed. It also contains no exports, because it doesn't contain any functions, which would be another argument against it having been rewritten. It's chock full of resources (images), but no executable code, as your dumpbin shows (see the .rsrc entry).

Comment: Does that mean that I can find the images in it, but not the "cdtInit()" functions advertised elsewhere?

Comment: I've never seen any *advertised* functions for the DLL, so I don't know to what you're referring. There are no exported functions shown in your dumpbin image, which means there is no `cdtInit` function for you to call in the DLL you're using. From my (years ago) experience, there is no executable functionality in the DLL; it's simply full of resources (bitmaps) with the card faces and various back of card images. (You apparently don't know about using @ to reach out to someone who has commented to you; lucky for you I stopped back by your post or I never would have seen your question.)

Comment: @KenWhite By "advertised", I mean this: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/using-cardsdll-api

Comment: I'm not familiar with that site, so I don't know what cards.dll might be in use with that code. All I can speak to is the dumpbin output you've provided, which shows there are **no** exported functions in that DLL, and my own past experience with the Cards.dll that shipped with Windows and was used in Solitaire (sol.exe) and Spider Solitaire, which had no executable code in it; it was a resource-only DLL, as I've mentioned before. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with the information at this link on [Catch22.net](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/using-cardsdll-api). The key learnings were:
`

```
static class NativeMethods
 {
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
 }
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 private delegate bool cdtInit(ref Int32 width, ref Int32 height);
 dll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"\path\cards32.dll");
 IntPtr addr;
 addr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(dll, "cdtInit");
 mycdtInit = (cdtInit)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addr, typeof(cdtInit));
 Int32 width = 71;
 Int32 height = 95;
 var result = mycdtInit(ref width, ref height);
```

`

Comment: I would appreciate knowing why this answer was downvoted. After all, it works, and the code IS in that DLL.